# Sharing RSA Public Key for decrypting JWT amongst Load Balanced servers

Tags: authentication, web-application, cookies, rsa

I'm trying to implement a cookie-less authentication mechanism for a web API that is stateless on the server (does not store session tokens) and can be load balanced across several servers.

I have implemented a JWT that gets returned to a client (mobile phonegap client) which gets stored in sessionStorage, and added to the header of post-authentication requests. While this works perfectly fine on a single server, I always want to have a standby server which can handle requests that initially authenticated on a different server. For this, I'm assuming that I will have to share keys amongst the different servers.

I don't understand the security implications of moving public or private keys across servers. Is it completely unadvisable? If so, how can I meet my requirements? If not, are there standard methods for sharing keys? For example, a distributed config service like etcd? Manual ssh transfers? Is it more advisable to have a single server handling authentication, and then just share the public keys amongst the servers for decrypting the token for calls to the rest of the API?

Comment: For clarification: You want clients to be able to authenticate between multiple servers?

Comment: I want a client to be able to log in on any server, and receive a token for the session that can sent via header to be decrypted on any other server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to share keys AND you use asymmetric keys then you can key each server separately and have each server set a different `iss` (issuer) claim. Then the recipient of the JWT can "look up" the appropriate public key based on the `iss` claim. Our lookup was basically a config file that mapped the `iss` value to a file system location of the public key.

If you need to share secret keys then I'd look at key distribution techniques. A lot will depend on how much effort you want to put in.

Comment: The iss claim encrypted in the token, isn't it?

Comment: @dannyone We used a signed JWT. Our API servers can look at the claims for `iss` and then pick the correct public key to verify the signature.

Comment: For people that confused to get `iss` value, some library provide a functionality to extract `iss` value from the token. Example: https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt/blob/3.2/README.md

Comment: Keep in mind that this only works for signed web tokens (JWS), not encrypted web tokens (JWE). The contents of a JWS are still visible.